# POSTMAN gives following Error "The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource"

Tags: spring, rest, jackson

I know the meaning of the error but can't debug it.

**My Bean class is** :

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

**My Controller is**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody User user, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
    System.out.println("Creating User " + user.getName());      
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/user/{id}").buildAndExpand(user.getName()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: What does your request look like?

Comment: Thanks its done. I appended the line <mvc:annotation-driven/> in my dispatcher-servlet.xml file and it started working.